# Dotnetnuke Multiple Page Add

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-settings

I am using Dotnetnuke page management to add pages to site, but it is not adding more than one page at a time when I list all the page names is the field provided with line breaks. I am using dotnetnuke version 7.

There are more than 50 pages to be added and it is taking a lot of time to add one by one.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in DNN's event viewer, or Javascript errors on the page?

Comment: I found this exception System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.

Comment: Strange... But I'm unable to reproduce the error. But can you reinstall or upgrade?